# Unable to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 to 20.04

Tags: 16.04, updates

I need to upgrade ubuntu 16.04 to 20.04.
When I use graphic interface, a pop-up windows tells me that all is updated and Ubuntu tells me that 18.04 must be installed first that it is normal.

But when I click nothing happens.

When I use the command line : `sudo do-release-upgrade`
I have the message :

> Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

I don't understand.
Anyone has an idea ?

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: 16.04 is no longer supported. You should reinstall.

Comment: You need to ensure your *xenial* or 16.04 system is fully-upgraded before you can *release-upgrade*. The error message is telling you that you haven't applied all 16.04 upgrades.  I'd suggest `sudo apt update` & read the messages, ensure there are no errors (or lines are missing), then `sudo apt full-upgrade` and providing all upgrades are applied (*and no sources are missing from the `apt update` you ran earlier*), you may need to reboot, then the `do-release-upgrade` should work.

Comment: @guiverc How the OP will be able to do `apt update`, since 16.04 is not supported?

Comment: Because of ESM the repositories are still available (some mirrors may not be, but the main archive is at least as are many mirrors).  @FedonKadifeli

Comment: Upgrading Ubuntu 16.04 or older to a currently supported version of Ubuntu such as 20.04 **is on topic* on Ask Ubuntu. see the help page: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you very much.

Yes, in fact, I had errors during `sudo apt update`. So I remove some deposits (skype and others). Now  it's ok. I can upgrade 16.04 to 18.04.

Comment: Please, add extra information to your "answer" after you do the upgrade to 18.04, and then, after you upgrade to 20.04.

Comment: If you plan to end up at 20.04, upgrading to 18.04 then immediately upgrading to 20.04 is a bad idea. You are better off cleanly installing 20.04

Comment: Don't forget to reboot in 18.04 at least, (*I would also check out the system there before your next upgrade*) then perform your next `do-release-upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

use `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt full-upgrade` and then upgrade to 18.04 and then to 20.04

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure your *xenial* or 16.04 system is fully-upgraded before you can *release-upgrade*.

The error message is telling you that you haven't applied all 16.04 upgrades.

I'd suggest

`sudo apt update`

and read the messages, ensure there are no errors (*or lines are missing*), then

`sudo apt full-upgrade`

and providing all upgrades are applied (*and no sources are missing from the `apt update` you ran earlier*), you may need to reboot, then the `do-release-upgrade` should work.